# Make instance variable accessible through hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In Rails, ActiveRecord objects, attributes are accessible via method as well as through Hash. Example:

```
user = User.first  # Assuming User to be inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base
user.name # Accessing attribute 'name' via method
user[:name] # Attribute 'name' is accessible via hash as well
```

How to make instance variables accessible through hash for classes not inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "through Hash", it's "array access" operator.

To implement it, you need to define methods:

```
def [](*keys)
  # Define here
end

def []=(*keys, value)
  # Define here
end
```

Of course, if you won't be using multiple keys to access an element, you're fine with using just `key` instead of `*keys`, so that you have not an array of keys (even if only one is given), but just a single key.

Plenty of other classes implement it, namely `Struct`s, so you're free to pick an existing implementation or roll out your own.

Getting instance variables to be affected by these methods means implementing them using `instance_variable_get`/`instance_variable_set`. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, in order to make attributes available as Hash and/or getter/setter, you can store the attributes in a single Hash and provide the corresponding getter/setter methods.

This is a fairly simple feature you can easily code directly into the target class.

In Ruby, there are also a couple of built-in libraries that provide a similar feature with slightly different approaches: [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Struct.html) and [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html).

Here's an example with an object defined using a `Struct`.

```
Customer = Struct.new(:name, :address, :zip)
joe = Customer.new("Joe Smith", "123 Maple, Anytown NC", 12345)

joe["name"]   #=> "Joe Smith"
joe[:name]    #=> "Joe Smith"
joe[0]        #=> "Joe Smith"
```

If you are using Rails, you can also include [`ActiveModel::Model`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) to have an ActiveRecord-like feature.